# SpriteKit - Class inheritance

Tags: class, inheritance, sprite-kit

I have this class Enemy.swift:

```
class Enemy: SKNode {

    var health = Int()
    var enemyPosition = CGPoint()
    var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
    var enemyName = String()

    func moveEnemy() {

              //Some Code
    }
}
```

And i use this in GameScene.swift:

```
func createEnemy() {

        var monster = Enemy()
        var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy-Sprite1")
        monster.guy = node
        monster.health = 4
        monster.enemyPosition = CGPointMake(10 ,  400)
        monster.guyName = "enemy1"
        monster.moveEnemy()
        self.addChild(monster)  
    }
```

But it doesn't work, it doesn't appear on the screen at all, and yes i do call it in "didMoveToView". What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: what is `enemyPosition`? Did you set  `monster.position`?

Comment: Do you add your SKSpriteNode to your monster node? As in monster.addChild(node)

Comment: @rakeshbs yes it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @AndyHeard i tried that, it foes show but i can't touch it, when i touch it detects the background, it's like it's not even there. But if i'm just going to add enemies to a certain enemy node then there are other simpler ways i guess.

Comment: Why not just subclass an SKSpritenode instead?

Comment: @rakeshbs the designated initialize would mess things up for me, either this or just a normal class so i have total control over the code.

Comment: rakeshbs is right, subclassing an SKSpriteNode instead of adding it as a child node would negate your issues as the normal SKNode has no area to tap in.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by total control of the code. You can write your own initialiser.

Comment: @rakeshbs it forces you to use a designated initialiser (texture:color:size)
Can you try doing something similar and see what you get ?

Comment: @Abdou023 You can create your own custom initializer when you subclass SKSpriteNode

Comment: @ZeMoon link to a tutorial or something ? because when i try it it always gives me an error for not using it's mandatory initiazlise, maybe i am missing something.

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25009021/2043580

Comment: @ZeMoon just a workaround, he does actually set the (texture-size-color), i don't get  why would i have  to set that on a sprite ?

Comment: Since it is a subclass of a SKSpriteNode, you have to use at least one initializer.

Comment: You need to call the designated `superclass` initialiser asin `super.init(texture:color:size:)` not any other ones. You can completely write your own initialiser (and pass nil to unused parameters in super.init)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass the `SKSpriteNode` instead of `SKNode`.

```
class Enemy : SKSpriteNode
{
    var health : Int = 0
    var enemyName : String = ""

    func moveEnemy() {

    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
var monster = Enemy(imageNamed: "Enemy-Sprite1")
monster.position = CGPointMake(10 ,  400)
monster.enemyName = "enemy1"
monster.health = 4
self.addChild(monster)
```

Comment: Yup, this is perfect. i don't want to mess my code with useless stuff like (init functions or coder,aDecoder).